# What is the origin of the ‘six pack’ flight instrument arrangement?

Tags: aviation-history, flight-instruments

I was wondering who came up with the modern ‘six pack’ flight instrument arrangement, when I realized that the old British blind instrument flying panel that was the standard across many airplane types in the 1940’s was very similar to the ‘six pack’. Is there a direct connection here with the Brits, because at least American aircraft of the era had instrument panels that appeared absurdly disorganized extending into the 1950’s? IOW, the British seemed to have a better idea of where flight instruments were best suited earlier on.

Comment: Before the six pack there was the "T"...

Comment: The T is part of the six pack.  I believe there was an FAA research project in the early 60s that identified the ideal arrangement for efficient scanning, and GA started to adopt it in the mid 60s. You can see the switch from scattergun arrangements to slightly more organized in the late 50s early 60s then the  T-six pack appears mid 60s.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I remember the "T" now.